# Bash script with a loop not executing utility that has paramters passed in?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, aix

Anyone able to help me out? I have a shell script I am working on but for the loop below the command after "echo "first file is $firstbd" is not being executed.. the $PROBIN/proutil ?? Not sure why this is...

Basically I have a list of files in a directory (*.list), I grab them and read the first line and pass it as a parameter to the cmdlet then move the .list and the content of the .list to another directory (the .list has a list of files with full path).

```
for i in $(ls $STAGEDIR/*.list); do
echo "Working with $i"
# grab first .bd file
firstbd=`head -1 $i`
echo "First file is $firstbd"
$PROBIN/proutil $DBENV/$DBNAME -C load $firstbd tenant $TENANT -dumplist $STAGEDIR/$i.list >> $WRKDIR/$i.load.log
#move the list and its content to finished folder
binlist=`cat $i`
for movethis in $binlist; do
    echo "Moving file $movethis to $STAGEDIR/finished"
    mv $movethis $STAGEDIR/finished/
done
echo "Finished working with list $i"
echo "Moving it to $STAGEDIR/finished"
mv $i $STAGEDIR/finished/
done
```

The error I was getting is..

./tableload.sh: line 107: /usr4/dlc/bin/proutil /usr4/testdbs/xxxx2 -C load /usr4/dumpdir/xxxxx.bd tenant xxxxx -dumplist /usr4/dumpdir/PUB.xxxxx.list >> /usr4/dumpdir/PUB.xxxx.list.load.log: A file or directory in the path name does not exist... however if I run "/usr4/dlc/bin/proutil"

The fix was to remove ">> $WRKDIR/$i.load.log".. the binary utility wouldn't run when trying to output results to file.. strange..

Comment: What's the output after the echo?

Comment: what does `$?` return after executing the script? >0 indicates something failed with the `$PROBIN` command or the `binlist` assignment.

Comment: error messages seldom lie `/usr4/dumpdir/PUB.xxxx.list.load.log: A file or directory in the path name does not exist`. Did you check that all dirs and files in that path have usable permissions and ownership? Even fixing that may uncover a new problem, but work thru errors as they appear. `ls -ld /usr4 /usr4/dumpdir /usr4/dumpdir/PUB.xxxx.list.load.log` may reveal some permissions or ownerships that are not set correctly.

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of other bugs in here -- many of them subtle. I'd strongly recommend running the script through http://shellcheck.net/ and working through its results. Reviewing http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Try `for movethis in $(cat $i)` - And execute the script using `bash -x` you are likely to spot the error immediately when arriving upon the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of really bad practices here

- parse the output of `ls`
- not quoting variables
- iterating the lines of a file with `cat` and `for`

As shelter comments, you don't check that you've created all the directories in the path for your log file.

A rewrite:

```
for i in "$STAGEDIR"/*.list; do
    echo "Working with $i"
    # grab first .bd file
    firstbd=$(head -1 "$i")
    echo "First file is $firstbd"
    # ensure the output directory exists
    logfile="$WRKDIR/$i.load.log"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$logfile")"
    "$PROBIN"/proutil "$DBENV/$DBNAME" -C load "$firstbd" tenant "$TENANT" -dumplist "$STAGEDIR/$i.list" >> "$logfile"
    # move the list and its content to finished folder
    while IFS= read -r movethis; do  
        echo "Moving file $movethis to $STAGEDIR/finished"
        mv "$movethis" "$STAGEDIR"/finished/
    done < "$i"
    echo "Finished working with list $i"
    echo "Moving it to $STAGEDIR/finished"
    mv "$i" "$STAGEDIR"/finished/
done
```